# calculating percentage in MDX

Tags: mdx, percentage

I'm trying to write a mdx query that would calculate the income percentage for each product in 3 different columns, depending on the percentage "base" - the Group (that the product is in) income, the subgroup income and total income. So far this is my code

```
    with 
member [Measures].[Percent] as
([Measures].[Income]) /
([Products].[product].currentmember.parent,
[Measures].[Income])
,format_string = "percent"

select 
    {
        [Measures].[Percent]
    }
    on columns,
    {
        [Products].[Product].[Product]
    }
    on rows
from [CUBE]
```

It calulates the percentage based on the total income, but I have no idea how to change the code to fill the criteria I mentioned earlier. I tried rearrenging the code many times in many different ways, (trying to calculate the sobgroup percentage example)

```
 with 
member [Measures].[Percent] as
([Measures].[Income], [Products].[Subgroup]) /
([Products].[product].currentmember.parent,
[Measures].[Income])
,format_string = "percent"
```

etc but I only get the same result or errors. I'm still very new to mdx so any help or tip would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a product - subgroup hierarchy in place?

Comment: The hierarchy is Group - Subgroup - Product

Comment: ok but there will be a user hierarchy with the levels in it AND there will be seperate attribute hierarchies for each of the levels in the user hierarchy. Can you add a link to a picture of the hierarchy structure?

Comment: Thank you for your time, I hope this is what you've asked for **[PICTURE](http://www110.zippyshare.com/i/9ZZSaudh/1429523/hierarchy.png)**

Comment: your user hierarchy looks like it is called `Hierarchy` ?! You will need to use this hierarchy as your original script was hitting the attribute hierarchy called Towar (with the 6 little squares next to it) I changed my script.

Comment: Yeah the towar means product, I translated the names so people could grasp the idea instantly. I used your new script and this time both SubCategory and Category are nulls, ofAll is working correctly though. This is my first mdx project, and every hierarchy  I have is called hierarchy (same in time dimension).

Comment: You could do with changing the hierarchy names to something a little more descriptive - it is fine having them as the same name in terms of the cube functioning but if anyone else wants to read your mdx they might get a little confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still a little unsure of the requirements but you can add an extra parent if you like:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Percent_ofSubCategory] as
   DIVIDE(
     [Measures].[Income]
    ,([Measures].[Income], [Towary].[Hierarchy].currentmember.parent)
   )
,format_string = "percent"
MEMBER [Measures].[Percent_ofCategory] as
   DIVIDE(
     [Measures].[Income]
    ,([Measures].[Income], [Towary].[Hierarchy].currentmember.parent.parent)
   )
,format_string = "percent"
MEMBER [Measures].[Percent_ofAll] as
   DIVIDE(
     [Measures].[Income]
    ,([Measures].[Income], [Towary].[Hierarchy].[All])
   )
,format_string = "percent"
SELECT 
    {
      [Measures].[Percent_ofSubCategory]
     ,[Measures].[Percent_ofCategory]
     ,[Measures].[Percent_ofAll]
    }
    on 0,
    [Towary].[Hierarchy].[Towar].[Towar].members
    on 1
from [CUBE];
```

Comment: **[PICTURE](http://www48.zippyshare.com/i/PxGUER4d/9174863/percent.png)** Is the result of your query. The hierarchy is Group - Subgroup - Product.

Comment: I've amended my script BUT I think you're using an attribute hierarchy - does a multi-level user hierarchy exist in your cube?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time but the script outcome is still the same. I'm not sure if it answer your question but the cube have 2 kind of measures (actual data and planned outcome) and 4 dimensions (Time, Clients, Regions, Products), each dimension, aside from client and region , have their hierarchy. Here's a  **[PICTURE](http://www110.zippyshare.com/i/9ZZSaudh/1429523/hierarchy.png)** of product hierarchy

Comment: Ok, I had to switch the  [Towary].[Hierarchy].[Towar].[Towar].members to  [Towary].[Hierarchy].[Towar].members but now it works, thank you!